# Tool for ongoing monitoring of a webserver?

Tags: monitoring, saas

I need to monitor a SaaS by going to a specific URL (is currently done either manually in a browser or by sending an HTTP request programatically in C# ) and if the response is other than HTTP response code 200, send an email and/or sms to predefined list of addresses/phone numbers.
 We'd like to be able to specify the number of the retries after which no request will be send for specified amount of time, and also have the tool not send any more alerts after sending a predefined number of them.

Is there an existing tool available that can perform the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nagios is my tool of choice for this sort of thing. Have a look [here](http://www.nagios.org/). It probably looks like overkill, but it certainly does exactly what you want. We have it running for about 200 devices (servers, printers, router, switches) and about 800 monitored services.

If you have detail questions about configuration, just post them here and I'll be glad to answer them.

Comment: +1 for Nagios.  My current Nagios setup monitors 200+ hosts, 700+ services.  If Nagios is more than you need, I'd bet you could script up something with wget or curl.

Comment: Another + for Nagios. You can configure people and groups of people, assign them to different monitoring alert periods (e.g., after hours support crews get alerts while 9-5ers don't). We also have it setup to send SMS warnings through a GPRS modem.

Comment: Nagios is overkill for this. A single subscription service like pingdom would be better.  You can also check out simple monitoring solution like isitup from tarosoft that I setup for our intental monitoring. http://www.tarosoft.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Pingdom](http://pingdom.com/) has a low cost service providing exactly what you describe.  You can monitor a single server for free.  5 servers is $9.95 per month.

Comment: I <3 pingdom. It's awesome, it's our primary system to monitor public websites.  It will monitor a url for specific phrase (i.e. to make sure your site doesn't have an error page on it). It can send a combo of sms and emails, even does twitter to multiple people.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is your best choice for onsite monitoring on Linux. For hosted ("cloud") monitoring we like [AlertFox](http://www.alertfox.com/). Unlike other services, it uses *real web browser* for transaction monitoring. I find that very useful. It is something that Nagios can not do out of the box so it complemnts our internal Nagios setup.

If you are on a tight budget, AlertFox has a free account option, but it is a bit hidden ([link here](http://www.alertfox.com/signup/)) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix has a web monitoring feature that provide what you needs. Hope this helps.